# How can an untrusted client prove that an ID isn't human meaningful?

Tags: validation, random

I have a situation where an untrusted client is generating string IDs, but I don't want them to be human readable.

They don't need to be crytographically random or even unique, I just don't want IDs like "idiot" to be accepted.

How can I go about preventing this?

EDIT: It would be nice if the IDs were "aspirationally-unique", like GUIDs.

Comment: Which programming language did you want a solution in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: @Tagc I don't think it matters too much, unless we come up with something crazy I'll be able to work out the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Convert the supplied ID to a hash or encrypt it. This will result in meaningless strings
- Create a dictionary of words you don't want used, and when the supplied ID contains one of those words, reject it... a PHP example can be found at https://scvinodkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/bad-word-filter-and-replace/
- Require that the IDs not contain sequences where two (or however many) alpha characters are next to each other

If you have any additional info/preference/requirements, let me know.

Comment: I think the hash strategy is the best option. Two remaining questions:

(1) Can we expect hash functions to be resistant to attacks which just try to make the first few bytes come out a specific way? (I'm planning to use blake2b but I'm interested in this question in general).

(2) Using a hash function will cause entropy loss. Should this be a concern when generating IDs that are mean to be aspirationally-globally unique? (similar to GUIDs)

Comment: Out of my depth on both questions unfortunately. RE (2): I would _expect_ not, as long as the ID supplied is unique. I'd prefer someone else to weigh in.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll think about the crypto stuff some and possibly open a new, more specific question about it. If I do I'll link to there from here.

Comment: Posted a question about the crypto issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821364/how-to-ensure-that-client-created-ids-arent-human-meaningful-with-a-hash